# meteor remove a record is not updating in the mongo server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteorite

```
var fanclub;
fanclub = Fanclub.findOne({"name" : e.target.value});

console.log(Fanclub.find().count());
Fanclub.remove({
  _id: fanclub._id
});
console.log(Fanclub.find().count());
```

I am trying to remove a record but always showing the one count less when I remove record but it is not updating the mongo db.

I have tried to use publish method but its not working. Can you please help in this

Comment: Server is probably denying remove, for latency compensation changes you do show immediately, but if server won't accept them it goes back to normal

Comment: So. what do I need to do it? Can you please give me a path to resolve this issue

Comment: if you've removed the `insecure` package, you need to set up a allow rules (specifically `remove`) - as per [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow).